# Como gerar um vetor usando Random para atribuir valores, mas fazer com que nunca tenha valores repetidos?

Tags: c#, array, random

Estou trabalhando em um **Bingo** em *C#* para um trabalho da facul e preciso fazer um vetor de tantos valores e fazer com que nunca repita esse valores, estou usando o seguinte procedimento para gerar os valores de **sorteio** ↓

```
public static void GeraBingo(int[] v)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i++)
        {
            v[i] = r.Next(1, 10); // gera 1 a 10 e vai gerar quantos o v.Count() mandar
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  // pausa 1000 miliseg.
        }
    }
```

Este código gera o vetor, mas não estou conseguindo assimilar um método para não entrar repetido.

Com este código acima eu consigo um vetor assim por exemplo:
**|9 |2 |5 |6 |5 |4 |2 |4 |6 |5 |**  e como é visível ele repete alguns valores.
Esse método é para trabalhar com apenas uma Array de valores int e não deixar com que se repita valores.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria você utilizar outra estrutura [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), o método Add, retorna `false` quando você insere um valor não único.

Comment: O shuffer yates é realmente uma solução para esse problema. Mas o seu problema pode ser um pouco diferente daquqle que o bigown marcou como duplicado. Por favor dê mais detalhes, inclusivamente responda à seguinte pergunta: Voce quer gerar  todos os números ou apenas parte deles? Se a resposta for parte deles, esta é uma pergunta diferente.

Comment: Os moderadores fazem o que bem entendem por aqui. Uma pergunta parece com a outra.

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar um array auxiliar com todos os valores disponiveis.:

```
public static int[] CriarLista(int min, int max) 
{
    var lista = new int[max - min + 1];
    for (var valor = min; valor <= max; valor++)
        lista[valor - min] = valor;
}

public static void GeraBingo(int[] v)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    var valores = CriarLista(1, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i++)
    {
        var indice = r.Next(1, 10) - 1;
        var valor = valores[indice];
        valores[indice] = valores[0];
        valores[0] = valor;

        v[i] = r.Next(1, 10); // gera 1 a 10 e vai gerar quantos o v.Count() mandar
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // pausa 1000 miliseg.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao que me parece o que você quer é colocar os números de um a dez em um vetor de dez posições, de forma aleatória. Se for isso mesmo, o que você precisa é de uma estrutura auxiliar da qual os números serão retirados de forma aleatória  semelhante àquela máquina do bingo de onde tiramos os números.

```
private int[10] _vetorResultado;
private List<int> _todosOsNumeros;

public int[] GeraBingo()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = _vetorResultado.Length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        _todosOsNumeros.add(i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < _vetorResultado.length; i++)
    {
        int bolaDaVez = _todosOsNumeros[r.Next(0, _todosOsNumeros.Count - 1)];

        _vetorResultado[i] = _todosOsNumeros.Remove(boladaVez); // Isso reduz o tamanho da fila de números pendentes
    }
    return _vetorResultado;
}
```

Note que você pode mudar o tamanho da estrutura que o algoritmo segue funcionando da mesma forma.

Note também que o método [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) da lista genérica não apenas remove o item como também retorna o valor removido.